# flutter how to make http post using form data?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make http post and I tried many times to make data-form about under parameters.

But I got a error message -{"IsOK":"false","ResultMessage":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: G. Path 'MethodName', line 1, position 13.","ResultCode":null,"EventResultYn":null}-

is there any way to make data-form with parameters in pictures?

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

void main() async {
  var url = 'https://www.lottecinema.co.kr/LCWS/Ticketing/TicketingData.aspx';
   
  // 1.
  /* var dic = {
    "MethodName": "GetPlaySequence",
    "channelType": "HO",
    "osType": "W",
    "osVersion":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "playDate": "2022-06-29",
    "cinemaID": "1|0001|1013",
    "representationMovieCode": ""
  };
  var parameters = {"paramList:" : dic};*/
   
  //2.
  var map = Map<String, String>();
  map["MethodName"] = "GetPlaySequence";
  map["channelType"] = "HO";
  map["osType"] = "W";
  map["osVersion"] =
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
  map["playDate"] = "2022-06-29";
  map["cinemaID"] = "1|0001|1013";
  map["representationMovieCode"] = "";
  var parameters = {"paramList": map};
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    // "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    // "Content-Type": "Application/json"
  }, body: parameters
  );

runApp(const MyApp());
```

And This is cURL.
[image]

I expect to response has data like this.

{Items: [{CinemaNameKR: "가산디지털", CinemaNameUS: "Gasan", MovieNameKR: "탑건: 매버릭",…},…], ItemCount: 10}

Comment: Can you share ciew source from browser's payload section ? or full curl request so can get idea

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundarya0i4XPiKkSy83I3P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paramList"

{"MethodName":"GetPlaySequence","channelType":"HO","osType":"W","osVersion":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","playDate":"2022-06-29","cinemaID":"1|0001|1013","representationMovieCode":""}
------WebKitFormBoundarya0i4XPiKkSy83I3P--

Comment: is this right source you want?

Comment: Please provide curl if posiible right click on request and  copy cUrl

Comment: You can click on view source and provide its screenshot

Comment: is your service running? does the service require any header? what content type does the API expect?

Comment: if i right click on request, there are 'copy >' and 'copy as cURL' . is that right what you want? @HardikMehta

Comment: yes do that please or you can share screenshot of it in question

Comment: I upload on answers is that right? Thank for your help!!

Comment: when i try your request in postman, i am getting 200 OK with the message {"IsOK":"false","ResultMessage":"ParamList가 존재하지 않습니다.","ResultCode":null,"EventResultYn":null}

Comment: @Prabhakaran 
if it was working right, then response is like this
 " {CinemaNameKR: "가산디지털", CinemaNameUS: "Gasan", MovieNameKR: "탑건: 매버릭",…}"

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But to my understanding it is not the fault of flutter. Need more inputs on APIs

Comment: You have to provide proper request or cURL so can get idea and this screenshot  is not making any sense: Please copy proper cURL request from  browser

Comment: Hardik Mehta, the cURL works fine for the API. I got the request from their website.

Comment: The issue might be that the request uses cookie data and he might not pass the correct one. That is why asking for more details on API

Comment: https://www.lottecinema.co.kr/NLCHS/Ticketing/Schedule in this URL, we can find the request.

Answer (score 0):

you must use multipart request

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:html/parser.dart';
    
    void main() async {
      var url = 'https://www.lottecinema.co.kr/LCWS/Ticketing/TicketingData.aspx';
       
      // 1.
      /* var dic = {
        "MethodName": "GetPlaySequence",
        "channelType": "HO",
        "osType": "W",
        "osVersion":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "playDate": "2022-06-29",
        "cinemaID": "1|0001|1013",
        "representationMovieCode": ""
      };
      var parameters = {"paramList:" : dic};*/
       
      //2.
      var map = Map<String, String>();
      map["MethodName"] = "GetPlaySequence";
      map["channelType"] = "HO";
      map["osType"] = "W";
      map["osVersion"] =
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
      map["playDate"] = "2022-06-29";
      map["cinemaID"] = "1|0001|1013";
      map["representationMovieCode"] = "";
      // var parameters = {"paramList": map};
      
         var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("$url"));
       request.fields.addAll(map);
  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
      var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      
     pring("STATUS CODE : ${response.statusCode}");
     pring("RESPONSE BODY : ${responseString}");
    
    runApp(const MyApp());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The result is RESPONSE BODY : {"IsOK":"false","ResultMessage":"ParamList가 존재하지 않습니다.","ResultCode":null,"EventResultYn":null}
"ParamList가 존재하지 않습니다." means 'paramList does not exist'

But if it work correctly, the result will be like this. " {CinemaNameKR: "가산디지털", CinemaNameUS: "Gasan", MovieNameKR: "탑건: 매버릭",…}"

Comment: this is not related to flutter. Please contact the person who wrote your API and request the correct request information.